# error 28105#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream

Tags: nginx, docker, virtualhost, php

I can't config `Nginx` with `php-fpm` correctly. When I get any php script, I get Nginx `404 Not found` error in browser:

```
File not found.
```

In my php-fpm logs I get:

```
172.17.42.1 -  28/Apr/2015:09:15:15 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
```

for any php script call and in Nginx logs I get:

```
[error] 28105#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.168.66.66:9000", host: "localhost"
```

My Nginx vitualhost config is:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  root /var/www/html;
  index index.html;

  server_name localhost;

  location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_pass    127.168.66.66:9000;
    #fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

I had spinning php-fpm Docker image from [official php repository](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/php/), that run by:

```
docker run -it -p 127.168.66.66:9000:9000 php:fpm
```

The `docker ps` command show next info:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES
dbf9f7d1c6f9        php:fpm             "php-fpm"           8 seconds ago       Up 7 seconds        127.168.66.66:9000->9000/tcp   serene_curie
```

What's wrong with my config?

P.S. Any static files (css, js, images) works on Nginx.

Comment: Sorry guys! I don't know that I also must to share my files to my php:fpm docker container too. I think it must work without sharing. The answer is to run docker image with volume: `docker run -it -p 127.168.66.66:9000:9000 -v /var/www/html/:/var/www/html/ php:fpm`

Comment: I am having the exact same problem as you.. I trying this on a new setup on centos 7 using PHP 5.6.8 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Apr 16 2015 14:45:51)

All my configs are setup correctly and I get file not found.. Have you managed to find the culprit as changing the fastcgi_param for the scripts to execute is not working and I have tried multiple params.

Comment: @oOo--STAR--oOo I fixed it. I forgot to share my files to the container and fpm throw this error

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Also, need to share files to the `php:fpm` docker container too. The answer is to run docker `php:fpm` image with volume too:

```
docker run -it -p 127.168.66.66:9000:9000 -v /var/www/html/:/var/www/html/ php:fpm
```

Comment: One more thing to note is that the nginx `root` directive path and docker volume destination path should be same.